# is this sampling from a simplex?

Tags: sampling, exponential-distribution

Simply,

if I sample $n$ $X_i$s from an exponential distirbution; that is
$$
X_i \sim exp(1)
$$

Then prove that the vector
$$
\left ( \frac{X_1}{\sum X_i}, \frac{X_2}{\sum X_i}, \cdots, \frac{X_n}{\sum X_i} \right )
$$

is sampled from the unit simplex in n-dimensions.

Comment: Just apply the definition: points on the simplex are those with non-negative coordinates summing to unity.  Can you demonstrate those facts about this vector?  If so, your job is then completed by observing there are $n$ coordinates.

Comment: This question is a specific example of the fact that independent draws from certain gamma distributions can be used to generate Dirichlet-distributed random vectors.

Comment: @whuber - I see. so I don't need anything beyond the definition of simplex? because how do I then take into consideration that these are draws from exponential. in fact the definition would apply for any arbitrary distribution that $X_i$ are sampled from. thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your claim is true for an *arbitrary* distribution? What if the *arbitrary* distribution has support over the real line? (Answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419751/why-is-softmax-function-used-to-calculate-probabilities-although-we-can-divide-e/419753#419753)

Comment: You are correct about arbitrary distributions--provided they always produce data of the same sign and have zero probability of producing all zeros.  The exponential is an example of that, but a Normal (for instance) would not be, nor would a Binomial (for the second reason).