# How do we know that Logistic regression actually returns the probability

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, model

My question is pretty straightforward... Logistic regression returns a non linear transformation of an affine transformation of the input data, that appears to be in $(0,1)$... my question is then, who are we sure that this is not just a number between 0 and 1, and instead is $P(y=1|x, w_{model})$?

I mean, in instead of the logistic function I would have used something like:
$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$$ I would still have outputs in $[0,1]$, but that does not mean that it's the probability that it's how sure is the model that $Y=1$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does logistic regression produce well-calibrated models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208867/why-does-logistic-regression-produce-well-calibrated-models)

Comment: @EikeP. actually not, that explains why LR is well calibrated, but gives no intuition on why we can consider that as a measure of certainty, even $tanh/2+.5$ gives a sort of probability, but that does not mean that we can consider it as a probability (and probably it's still well calibrated)

Comment: Logistic regression (binary regression using a logistic map from the linear predictor to the probability scale) is not the only way to define a model of probabilities. Common alternatives include probit and cloglog regression. The model using $f(x)$ that you propose is not identified because changing the sign of $x$ does not change the model's likelihood. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419751/why-is-softmax-function-used-to-calculate-probabilities-although-we-can-divide-e/419753#419753 Non-Monotonicity also means that it's not cadlag, so it's not a probability distribution.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Ah, sorry. Well yes, it's essentially an arbitrary simple nonlinear model that does not necessarily fit the true probability exactly. Any monotonically non-decreasing function with outputs in [0, 1] could be used instead, I guess? (You might be interested in reading up on isotonic regression for model calibration.)

Comment: @Sycorax makes sense but what about tanh/2+.5? than it has all the properties that you have described, but it has no connection to a probability

Comment: It satisfies the required definitions; that's sufficient on its face. Additionally, note that $\tanh(x) = 2\sigma(2x) - 1$ where $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-x)}$, which should make its connection to probability even more explicit.